# How to make TextBlock selectable in Flyout (XAML)?

Tags: xaml, uwp

My XAML code:

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <TextBlock Text="Text is not selectable here" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </Flyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

Despite I set IsTextSelectionEnabled - the text is not selectable in Flyout.
Is it possible to make the text selectable ? I tried RichTextBlock - it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set [AllowFocusOnInteraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.allowfocusoninteraction) property as true on the AppBarButton to get focus.

```
<AppBarButton AllowFocusOnInteraction="True">
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <TextBlock Text="Text is not selectable here" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </Flyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```